# Mapkit Multiple Annotations

Tags: annotations, location, mapkit

I'm having some problems with adding annotations, I'm currently making an app that displays all pizza places near your location. I know how to display the current location, but I need help with MapKit. I want to display the pizza places but I also want it to print the name and the phone number (in Xcode). What lines of code do I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

**How to add one map annotation:**

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 10.0, longitude: 59.0)
annotation.title = "Pizza Place"
annotation.subtitle = "Phone: 0012345678"
map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

**A function to add multiple Pizza Place annotations:**

```
func addPizzaPlacesToMap(places: [PizzaPlace]) {

    // Remove all annotations from map
    self.map.removeAnnotations(self.map.annotations)

    // Loop trough all your pizza places and add them to the map
    for place in places {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = place.name
        annotation.subtitle = place.phone
        annotation.coordinate = place.coordinate
        self.map.addAnnotation(anno)
    }

}
```

Comment: But that would be for only one Pizza Place, what if I want to add multiple places? for a whole city?

Comment: This code adds one single point, if you want to add more you have to do it several times. This could be done by looping trough a list of pizza places and adding an annotation for each and one of them. Do you have an array of Pizza places?

Comment: I already tried adding each annotation one by one and it takes a lot of work to do. What I want is a function similar to local search request but instead of that I want the pizza places to appear by default.

Comment: Is your main problem showing the pizza places? Or is it to actually get a list of pizza places?

Comment: My main problem is showing the pizza places, but I want to use a function to show them

Comment: Okay, I added a function to add multiple pizza places to the map :)